# Is there any personally identifying info in compiled .NET code?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, cil

Not that I have anything to hide :), but if I compile and deploy my .NET code, is there any way anyone (MS, government), can determine any information about the author by examining/decompiling the IL?  Whether it be a GUID related to the author's installation of Visual Studio, or perhaps some build checksum sent to MS, or some other hidden 'tag'?  I'm not referring to incidental metadata like timestamps or coding style fingerprinting; just intentional or sufficient tracking metadata.

Comment: That's a very vague question. Especially since applications are usually built using CI/CD pipelines using command-line tools, not Visual Studio. VMs. Containers. The things you describe are *not* personally identifying information either. Tools do ask you to send anonymized telemetry but these are they key words: anonymized and ask. When you install the .NET SDK and try build for the first time you're asked, warned and given a way to turn off telemetry. I never do

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, but even those tools were downloaded from MS, installed, and can possibly be marking the builds.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, maybe my question should be, "Quick question if anyone already knows: in the open source roslyn C# compiler (https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn), is there any part of its compilation process that stamps the generated IL in a manner that can trace it back to the specific compiler-install/build-machine/author?"

Comment: Also, you cannot be sure that the tool doing the compiling is not sending some information that "registers" your code in the cloud.  You'd want to compile on a air gapped computer to be safe.

Comment: If you do code signing then not only do you have identifying information, you have *provable* identifying information, as the code was signed using your certificate and therefore could only have come from you. As far as anything else is concerned, I don't believe there is any other identifying info. Guids are not a concern since they now use Type 4 UUIDs which are pretty much random

Comment: Thanks @charlieface.  I don't believe they would advertise any tracking metadata in the IL output, though it's not inconceivable given the counterintelligence efforts in play

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft [assembly manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/manifest), there is no identifying information. You can add optional assembly attributes.  If you wanted to be sure you'd want to compile as different people and compare the assemblies bit-by-bit.

Comment: Thanks Rich.  This I think addresses whether there's obvious tagging, but I'm more concerned with hidden tagging, even as innocuous as an embedded Guid in the IL that isn't documented.  Call me paranoid, but I have to believe this feature would be of great interest to governments or law enforcement

Comment: Having been politically active in my prior life; I understand your thinking Sean.  Your paranoia can be described as survival.  If you are working on things that concern you than be careful. I believe that I was brown listed for jobs for a while until I quit posting on social media, so your fear is warranted. There are secret columns in databases, this is known. There could be supervisor in ALL of our software at a level we are not aware, it's what I'd do if I was in control.

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer, but seems to suggest there's no additional fingerprinting (yet)

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/discussions/63102